# How is the Ice Wall still intact?

Tags: game-of-thrones

The Night King destroyed the wall and Castle black in *Game of Thrones* season 7. However, in the ending scenes of season 8 we see that the wall is Intact?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The Night King only destroyed a very small portion of the wall at the very east end. The castle there is Eastwatch-by-the-Sea, not Castle Black. Castle black is roughly at the center of the wall.

There is no indication that that section of the wall was repaired and its likely still a big pile of rubble

Comment: Eastwatch is roughly 150 miles from Castle Black.

Comment: So that was East Watch, hmm makes sense now!

Comment: You can see 'Last Hearth', and the section of wall in the intro flyover - https://cdn.vox-cdn.com/thumbor/nYVLDH230KXMGqC4oql7mxoiA6A=/0x0:2561x1440/1200x800/filters:focal(1077x516:1485x924)/cdn.vox-cdn.com/uploads/chorus_image/image/63409340/Screenshot_28.0.png